# WebStorm - Suppress unused param warning JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jslint

Does anyone know how to suppress unused parameter warning in WebStorm? I tried jslint, but that does not work

```
/*jslint node: true, unparam: true*/
/*global __dirname: false */
"use strict";
var
  util = require('../util'),
  logger = util.getLogger(module.filename),
  ;

var UserHelper = module.exports = function () {
};

/**
 * Helper object for user facade 
 */
UserHelper.prototype = {
  doSomething : function(unusedParam) {
    //do something implementation
  }
};
```

Comment: unparam should work. Can you post your code?

Comment: Consider [using jshint instead of jslint](https://web.archive.org/web/20130819215629/http://anton.kovalyov.net/2011/02/20/why-i-forked-jslint-to-jshint/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jshint` instead of `jslint` works for me on WebStorm 8 and WebStorm 9 beta:

```
/*jshint node:true, unused:false */
```

Also, make sure you have JSHint (or JSLint) enabled in your preferences. JSHint has "Warn about unused variables". NOTE: This JSHint check does not distinguish between variables and function parameters *unless* JSHint is configured with `unused:vars`.

You can also uncheck the "Unused parameters" option under the JSLint configuration screen.

Relevant [JSHint doc](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#unused)

Comment: Not really a jslint answer.  ;^)

Comment: OP didn't ask for jslint specifically, just a way to turn off the unused param warning.

Comment: does that remove the warnings for you in webStorm? It did not work for me. I'm not getting any lint errors but warnings in WebStrom editor

Comment: @sherb unused:vars can be used instead of unused:false. This makes sure that unused variables are flagged but not unused function parameters

Comment: @sherb -- since there was a jslint tag and no jshint tag, I figured he wanted a jslint solution. Guess not! Either way, it looks like a WebStorm configuration issue; I can get his code through JSLint.com (if I correct the other errors).

Answer (score 5):

You can modify WebStorm's builtin code inspections under File->Settings->Editor->Inspections. Then in Javascript->General area look for "Unused JavaScript / ActionScript global symbol".

That is likely the setting which is causing the "unused property" warning, though it might be one of the others. I am using 2016.1.3 and noticed a lot of my anonymous functions defined like this had the same buggy warning. Like most others I'd still recommend using jsHint itself above and beyond even just WebStorm's inspection.

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 4):

For WebStorm with JSLint/JSHint disabled, you need to add this line before the line triggering the error:

```
//noinspection JSUnusedLocalSymbols
```

Answer (score 0):

`unparam` should work -- and if I clean the other lint issues your sample, it does.

```
/*jslint node: true, unparam: true, sloppy:true, white:true, nomen:true */
/*global __dirname: false */
"use strict";
var util = require('../util'),
  logger = util.getLogger(module.filename),
  UserHelper;

UserHelper = module.exports = function () {
    console.log('this is a function');
};

/**
 * Helper object for user facade 
 */
UserHelper.prototype = {
  doSomething : function(unusedParam) {
    //do something implementation
    console.log('alert');
  }
};
```

That passes cleanly on jslint.com.  Sounds like a WebStorm configuration issue.  I have PhpStorm 6.x, but I'm assuming you're on the latest version of WebStorm, so I can't guarantee I could debug it.

But it certainly seems like a WebStorm issue rather than a JSLint one.

Comment: I'm not getting lint errors but warnings in WebStorm

Comment: I'm pretty sure [the WebStorm errors *are* from JSLint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/jslint.html). WebStorm has JSLint built-in. Simply turn it off if it's bothering you and you'd prefer not to fix the code.